# Garbage collection promotes but does not move object

Tags: .net, garbage-collection, clr, cil, il

I'm playing with the **.Net GC** (for educational purpose only) and I'm surprised by its behavior.

I've built a basic program that :

- creates an object
- displays the address of its single field and its current generation
- runs a collection
- displays address and generation a second time
- runs a second collection
- displays address and generation a third time

I expected address and generation to change each time, as the object is promoted from one generation to the next, and moved from one memory area to the next.

This is true for the **generation which gets incremented** at each collection but **the field's address is always the same**.

Here is the **IL** code:

```
.assembly GCGenerationsSample { }
.assembly extern mscorlib { }

.class A extends [mscorlib]System.Object
{
    .field int32 n;

    .method instance void .ctor()
    {
        ldarg.0
        call instance void [mscorlib]System.Object::.ctor()
        ret
    }
}

.method static void Main()
{
    .entrypoint

    .locals (class A)

    newobj instance void A::.ctor()
    stloc.0

    // Display address of field "n"
    ldloc.0
    ldflda int32 A::n
    call void [mscorlib]System.Console::WriteLine(int32)

    // Display generation of object
    ldloc.0
    call int32 [mscorlib]System.GC::GetGeneration(object)
    call void [mscorlib]System.Console::WriteLine(int32)

    // Run a full GC
    call void [mscorlib]System.GC::Collect()

    // Display address of field "n"
    ldloc.0
    ldflda int32 A::n
    call void [mscorlib]System.Console::WriteLine(int32)

    // Display generation of object
    ldloc.0
    call int32 [mscorlib]System.GC::GetGeneration(object)
    call void [mscorlib]System.Console::WriteLine(int32)

    // Run a full GC
    call void [mscorlib]System.GC::Collect()

    // Display address of field "n"
    ldloc.0
    ldflda int32 A::n
    call void [mscorlib]System.Console::WriteLine(int32)

    // Display generation of object
    ldloc.0
    call int32 [mscorlib]System.GC::GetGeneration(object)
    call void [mscorlib]System.Console::WriteLine(int32)

    ret
}
```

And the output:

```
39070896
0
39070896
1
39070896
2
```

Either I'm missing something, or doing something stupid, or both (highly probable).

Any idea is more than welcome.

Comment: That's just not the way it works.  Promoting the objects in an ephemeral segment to the next generation is done by moving the segment to the next generation, not the objects.  That just takes a simple pointer change, no need to move all the objects.  The segment is replaced with a new segment, either by recycling an old one or allocating a new one.

Comment: @HansPassant: thanks again for your insight Hans. :) So that means a generation is not a continuous memory area but a virtual area, that may be discontinuous, resulting of the aggregation of segments? And objects will be moved physically only when there is compaction I guess?

Comment: It is just a chunk of VM space, allocated with VirtualAlloc().  Only gen#2 is "discontinuous", a collection of segments that were once the gen#0 and gen#1 segments.

Comment: Ok, thanks. I have a last question. AFAIK gen#0 is "small", something like 256K, probably fitting the CPU cache size, so it's a lot less than a segment which is something like 16MB (and precisely the size of gen#1?). So how the GC manages this difference? It can't always naively promote a full segment from gen#0 to gen#1 then to gen#2.

Comment: Indeed say gen#0 is filled a first time, its segment is promoted and becomes the gen#1, and the GC asks the OS for a new segment which becomes the gen#0. Latter gen#0 is full again, gen#1 segment becomes first gen#2 segment. And a third time we fill the gen#0. Then IMHO the GC could/should copy the data from gen#0 to gen#1 instead of asking for a new segment because it has still plenty of memory to use in gen#1. It already has 3 segments, one per generation, that are mostly unused.

Comment: The gen#0 segment size is dynamically adjusted, starting at 2MB.  An empty generation doesn't get promoted.

Comment: @HansPassant: OK, so at some point in the future its size will converge to the size of a segment, avoiding any waste from this point? Thanks again Hans for taking the time to share. Please add an answer so that I can accept it. :)

Answer (score 1):

For it to move you'll need to allocate something before the object that is surviving generations that gets collected so the surviving object has some space to compact into.

Your object is always at the start of the heap so it doesn't need to move anywhere.

Comment: Yes it's the behavior described by Hans and that I've validated too with compaction (code not here). And the object is not at the start of the heap, but the start of its segment. :)